# I can't figure out how to use the localStorage function correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hidden div that unlocks after the script is executed, I need it to remain unlocked after the page is reloaded for the user who has passed the check. If possible, then set a timer, after which it will be blocked again after the page is reloaded.

```
$(function() {
  $('#podt').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/inc/test_code_sms.php', $('#form1').serialize(), function(data) {
      alert(data)
      if (data == ("Номер активирован")) {
        let content = document.getElementById("content")
        content.style.display = "block"
        localStorage.setItem('content', 1);
      };
    });
  });
});

localStorage.getItem('content'); //1
```

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: _"I need it to remain unlocked after the page is reloaded"_ - then you should probably write code, that actually does the unlocking, after the page was loaded - currently, you are only adding a click handler.

Comment: `if (localStorage.getItem('content')) document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";`